# SharedGridSize group with ItemsControl embedded Grids

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, layout, sharedsizegroup

I am trying to embed multiple grids within another grid using an `ItemsControl` and have all the child grids share the same row heights:

```
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ControlItems}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <CustomPanel></CustomPanel>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.DataTemplate>
            <CustomControl/>
        </ItemsControl.DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

Where CustomControl is actually a customized Grid something like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="CustomControlGroup" />
        <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="CustomControlGroup" />
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

However the rows in the child grids do not share the same size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well according to this [article](http://wpftutorial.net/GridLayout.html#sharedsize). You must set the `IsSharedSizeScope` property in a parent control to `True`. So probably it should look more like:

```
<ItemsControl Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="CustomControlGroup" />
            <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="CustomControlGroup" />
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    </Grid>
</ItemsControl>
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751905.aspx) is another example from the MSDN. IMHO, the first article is more understandable.