# How to reuse slightly different DataTemplate elements?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatemplate, wpf-grid

In WPF, I have defined a grid of elements. They will be shown or collapsed depending on the properties of objects in an array in the `ViewModel`.

In the XAML file, the `DataTemplate` looks like this:

```xml
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type implementationInputDevices:InputDevicesViewModel}">
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
        ...

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" 
                   Grid.Column="0" 
                   Text="{Binding MyArray[0].Name}" 
                   Visibility="{Binding MyArray[0].Visible}"/>
        <ComboBox  Grid.Row="1" 
                   Grid.Column="1" 
                   Visibility="{Binding MyArray[0].Visible}" 
                   SelectedItem="{Binding MyArray[0].Foo}" 
                   ItemsSource="{Binding Bar}"/>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" 
                   Grid.Column="0" 
                   Text="{Binding MyArray[1].Name}" 
                   Visibility="{Binding MyArray[1].Visible}"/>
        <ComboBox  Grid.Row="2" 
                   Grid.Column="1" 
                   Visibility="{Binding MyArray[1].Visible}" 
                   SelectedItem="{Binding MyArray[1].Foo}"
                   ItemsSource="{Binding Bar}"/>
        ...

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="n" 
                   Grid.Column="0" 
                   Text="{Binding MyArray[n-1].Name}" 
                   Visibility="{Binding MyArray[n-1].Visible}"/>
        <ComboBox  Grid.Row="n" 
                   Grid.Column="1" 
                   Visibility="{Binding MyArray[n-1].Visible}" 
                   SelectedItem="{Binding MyArray[n-1].Foo}"
                   ItemsSource="{Binding Bar}"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

As you can see, I am using the same block of elements for every row, but with slightly different values.
This is very inconvenient as adding new rows needs manual adjustments and adding a row above (inside this grid) needs even more.

Can I define the set of elements once and reuse them with a simple command? Something like this:

```xml
<MyRowElement n="1" />
<MyRowElement n="2" />
...
<MyRowElement n="k" />
```

Comment: Can i ask you why are you not simply using an observable collection ? Instead of binding to MyArray[index].property, you create an observable collection of object that will be bound to a control like a listbox where you specify that each item will be composed of a textblock and a combobox. You can achieve what you want with a data template selector, but honestly this approach it's very ugly to me

Comment: I removed the forced tag from your question's title. Please read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) why.

Comment: Instead of a hard-coded grid, you should use an `ItemsControl`. You can use a `Grid` as the `ItemsPanel`. Start with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16559186/wpf-sharedgridsize-group-with-itemscontrol-embedded-grids).

Answer (score 0):

Create an `UserControl`

```
<UserControl x:Class=.......UcMyUserControl >
    <Grid >
        ......... <!-- RowDefinition, ColDefinition ... -->
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" 
                    Grid.Column="0" 
                    Text="{Binding Name}" 
                    Visibility="{Binding VisibleProperty}"/>
        <ComboBox  Grid.Row="1" 
                    Grid.Column="1" 
                    Visibility="{Binding VisibleProperty}" 
                    SelectedItem="{Binding Foo}" 
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Bar}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And in your `View` use an `ItemsControl` (like **dymanoid** said)

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="itmWrapPanel" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding MyArray, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  
            ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
            >

    <!-- Panel Type -->
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <!-- StackPanel || WrapPanel -->
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  
                    Background="White" 
                    AllowDrop="True" 
                    Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=itmWrapPanel}" 
                    Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=itmWrapPanel}"  />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <!-- ItemTemplate / Your Template -->
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate  >
            <local:UcMyUserControl  />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

For more information search for `ItemsControl`, you will find a lot that can help you more

Look this example all itens here is an usercontrol, all items in the image are independent of each other and all are the same usercontrol, nested in an `ItemsControl`
[image]